# How can i quit a function once something happens?

Tags: swift, function

I have a function that runs in my code currently. The function runs a loop that indexes an array with information in it. Once it finds a certain value, i want to stop the function from running. Is there an easy way to do this?

Below is the code i currently have:

```
func myFunction() {
   for i in 0...10 {
        if cell.value == myArray[i]{
            cell.identifier.isHidden = false
            // this is where I want to stop the function

        }
        else {
            cell.identifier.isHidden = true
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: Please read the [Control Flow](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html) chapter of the Swift book (as well as the rest of it).

Comment: More efficient: `func myFunction() { cell.identifier.isHidden = !myArray.contains(cell.value) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exit the function by calling `return`.